# How to take derivative using the Math Palette

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, palettes

I have a basic question on how to take derivatives using Math Palettes:

I would like to get the derivative of `cos(k*x - w*t)` with respect to `x`

Typing `D[Cos[k*x - w*t], x]` successfully returns `k Sin[t w - k x]`, but I also want to learn to do it using Math Palette. When I use the tool like I did below, I cannot do it. How do I fix this? What am I doing wrong?

[image: Math palette]

Comment: How did you get those differential ds? Did you copy them from the integral expression? Which palette are you using?

Comment: The fancy notation for derivatives is like this in Mathematica: `\!\(\*SubscriptBox[\(\[PartialD]\), \(x\)]\(x^2\)\)` (copy this to a notebook to see it formatted)

Comment: @MarcoB, I got the d's from Palettes > Basic Math Assistant > Typesetting.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The palette's typesetting shortcut *Derivative notation* which looks like this:

[image: deriv_notate]

is intended for inline math typesetting in a text cell. You use it typeset math expressions in text cells. Like this:

[image: math]

To take a derivative in a calculation, i.e., in an input cell, use the *Single variable derivative* shortcut.

[image: derivative]